# Installation of TagHighlight

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vi, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to install the [TagHighlight](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2646) vim script.

I am using MacVim version 7.4.22 and Mac OS X  10.9.3. I unzip the zip file and then copy into `~/.vim`. However, there are no changes when I start editing a C++ file, in that there is no extra syntax highlighting.

Is there something that I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: The plugin is probably badly installed and you almost certainly didn't read [the documentation](https://bitbucket.org/abudden/taghighlight/src/74fecd145d23025d5d66f7f4e32d46003459129a/doc/TagHighlight.txt?at=default).

Comment: The installation instructions given in the documentation are identical to those given on the link that is on the download site for the vim script: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2646

Comment: You didn't tell us what you have : what files are where?